# Google Cloud Managed Instance Group Rolling Update for Webbservers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm looking for the right solution for my problem.

The problem is this: Performing a rolling update on all the webservers in the instance group without serving different content at the same time and achieving 0 downtime.

I have a deployment machine, which serves as a testing-ground, before an update is scheduled to roll out, all the new content gets deployed on this machine and is tested (this machine is supposed to be the most up to date webbserver), when content is verfied and there is no issues with the update, the following steps are taken.

- Creating a snapshot of the deployment machine
- Creating an image of the snapshot
- Creating an instance template referring to the new image
- Performing either a rolling update or a rolling/restart-replace operation on the instance group with the new instance template

I'm not able to achieve 0 downtime even though i've set "Maximum unavailable" to zero, nor am i serving just the content from the newly updated machine the moment the first compute instance comes online, which results in serving 2 different versions at the same time.

Servers are unresponsive 1-10 seconds and i get the classic `<h2>The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.</h2>` error.

Is there an easier way to go about this without having to fall back to configuring my own Haproxy compute instance and perform the following steps.

- Disable % servers in the loadbalancer
- Rsync content to disabled servers
- Enable updated servers
- Disable remaining % servers in the loadbalancer
- Rsync content to disabled servers
- Enable updated servers

This must have been done flawlessly with "regular" (ex LAP) instances not just docker images, though i cannot find any resource on this topic.

> EDIT:
>   By doing a rolling-update by editing the instance group, changing the instance template and doing a rolling replace operation results in zero downtime, i find it odd that the rolling-update function can't achieve this aswell.

Would really appreciate your input.

Comment: Just love it when you downvote and give no good reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rolling update is a gradual process to update your instances. Striving for 0 downtime should be achievable, however serving different content will be seen because of how rolling updates work.
In order to make your servers more responsive and less disruptive, please have a look at the following two strategies:

[Max surge](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/updating-managed-instance-groups?hl=en_US&_ga=2.158638522.-1028673997.1532983356&_gac=1.174834966.1533939808.EAIaIQobChMI5riNg8Pj3AIVAtlkCh1ACgUuEAAYASAAEgLIK_D_BwE#max_surge). This will create instances above the target size in order to speed up the update process.

[Opportunistic update](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/updating-managed-instance-groups?hl=en_US&_ga=2.158638522.-1028673997.1532983356&_gac=1.174834966.1533939808.EAIaIQobChMI5riNg8Pj3AIVAtlkCh1ACgUuEAAYASAAEgLIK_D_BwE#starting_an_opportunistic_or_proactive_update). “An opportunistic update is only applied when new instances are created by the managed instance group”